# Sum of even binomial expansions 1 more than sum of odd terms

Tags: combinatorics

In a binomial expansion $$(1+2)^n = \sum_{i=0}^n{n\choose i}2^{n-i}$$
Why is the sum of the even $i$ 1 greater than the sum of the odd $i$?

Comment: The sum of the even is exactly the sum of the odd. Many proofs, for example put $X=-1$ in the formula of your post.

Comment: OK I changed it to X=2 case only. I guess it's not true for all N

Comment: The difference of the even and odd terms in the expansion of $(1+2)^n$ is the expansion of $(1-2)^n$.

Comment: Thanks for your answer.. why is that?

Comment: Rewrite as $\sum_{k=0}^{\lfloor n/2\rfloor} \binom{n}{2k}2^{n-2k}-\binom{n}{2k+1}2^{n-2k-1}=\sum_{k=0}^{\lfloor n/2\rfloor} \binom{n}{2k}(-2)^{n-2k}+\binom{n}{2k+1}(-2)^{n-2k-1}$, since $(-1)^{2k}=1$ and $(-1)^{2k+1}=-1$.

Comment: @John Forster: Before you edited your post, I thought that you were noticing that the sum of the coefficients of the even powers of $x$ (including the constant term $x^0$) is the same as the sum of the coefficients of odd powers of $x$. For example, look at $(1+x)^4=1+4x+6^2+4x^3+x^4$. We have $1+6+1=4+4$. Same is true for $(1+x)^n$.

Comment: @hoyland Where to go from what you've written to get the difference of 1?

Answer (score 1):

Just fleshing out what's already in various comments:

$$\eqalign{\sum_{i{\rm\ even}}{n\choose i}2^{n-i}-\sum_{i{\rm\ odd}}{n\choose i}2^{n-i}&=\sum_{i{\rm\ even}}(-1)^i{n\choose i}2^{n-i}+\sum_{i{\rm\ odd}}(-1)^i{n\choose i}2^{n-i}\cr&=\sum_{i=0}^n(-1)^i{n\choose i}2^{n-i}=\sum_{i=0}^n(-1)^n{n\choose i}(-2)^{n-i}\cr&=(-1)^n\sum_{i=0}^n{n\choose i}(-2)^{n-i}=(-1)^n(1-2)^n=1}$$